# Change ID of an element where Class is X

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to change the ID of a div via Ajax.
Because the ID has a dynamic value I added a class to the div.

My php code:

```
    echo '<div id="pagemenu">
            <ul id="tabpanel">';
$tel = 0;
while($totaalklanten > -4)
{
    $tel++;
    echo '<li><a href="#'.$tel.'" name="'.$tel.'" onclick="listklant(\'klant.php\',this.name)">'.$tel.'</a></li>';
    $totaalklanten = $totaalklanten - 5;
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<div class="changeme" id="default">';
//Lots of query of php stuff here to execute
echo '</div>
```

The div with the class 'changeme' is the victim.

My Ajax code so far:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function listklant(serverPage, pagenum)
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);



    document.getElementsByClassName('changeme').id = pagenum;
    alert(document.getElementById(pagenum));
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('changeme').id);


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

The first alert gives me 'null' :(...
Yet the second alert gives me the right value, so 'pagenum' was applied succesfully.
What am I doing wrong? And how to fix it?
(If there is anything else I can improve, please give a shout)

Comment: Why is this flagged as @php? And @ajax? This is at best @javascript.

Comment: I added the javascript tag... I tagged it php and Ajax because there might be an error in my php, ajax or javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This question is way older than the other one. Why would you mark it as duplicate?

Comment: The age of the question is irrelevant. [Old question marked as duplicate of a new question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('changeme').id = pagenum;
```

This line of code does **not** set the `id` of elements with the class `changeme`. `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` containing the elements.  You are setting an `id` property on the `NodeList`.  Obviously, this is not reflected on the elements within the list.

To do this, work on the elements themselves.  If you have one element with the class, that is simple:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('changeme')[0].id = pagenum;
```

If you have more elements, you'll need a loop:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('changeme');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
    els[i].id = pagenum;
}
```

However, it's probably a bad idea to change an element's `id`.  Using a class might well be a better idea here.

---

**Edit** To explain why your second `alert` works, it is because the same `NodeList` is returned by the call to `getElementsByClassName`.  From [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#dom-getelementsbyclassname):

> When the method [`getElementsByClassName`] is invoked on an HTMLElement object again with the same argument, the user agent may return the same object as the object returned by the earlier call.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the problem. I didn't know it was an array :)... Thanks again!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Technically it's not an array -- it's a `NodeList`, which behaves in an array-like manner.