# What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, dom-traversal

Do `getElementsByClassName` (and similar functions like `getElementsByTagName` and `querySelectorAll`) work the same as `getElementById` or do they return an array of elements?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to change the style of all elements using `getElementsByClassName`. See below.

```
//doesn't work
document.getElementsByClassName('myElement').style.size = '100px';

//works
document.getElementById('myIdElement').style.size = '100px';
```

Comment: The clue is, very much, in the name: `getElementsByClassName()` implies a plural, whereas `getElementById()` implies a singular element item.

Comment: I get that, it just didn't make sense to me that you can't change all the elements with that class name using the code above instead of having to loop through an array. jquery way is much better, i was just curious about the js way

Comment: Might be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Your [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) code works since IDs have to be unique and thus the function always returns exactly one element (or `null` if none was found).

However, the methods
[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName),
[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName),
[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), and
[`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS)
return an iterable collection of elements.

The method names provide the hint: `getElement` implies *singular*, whereas `getElements` implies *plural*.

The method [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) also returns a single element, and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns an iterable collection.

The iterable collection can either be a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) or an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

[`getElementsByName`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-document-object) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode) are both specified to return a `NodeList`; the other [`getElementsBy*` methods](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) are specified to return an `HTMLCollection`, but please note that some browser versions implement this differently.

Both of these collection types don’t offer the same properties that Elements, Nodes, or similar types offer; that’s why reading `style` off of `document.getElements`…`(`…`)` fails.
In other words: a `NodeList` or an `HTMLCollection` doesn’t have a `style`; only an `Element` has a `style`.

---

These “array-like” collections are lists that contain zero or more elements, which you need to iterate over, in order to access them.
While you can iterate over them similarly to an array, note that they are [*different*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29707568) from [`Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

In modern browsers, you can convert these iterables to a proper Array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from); then you can use `forEach` and other [Array methods, e.g. iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods):

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myElement"))
  .forEach((element) => element.style.size = "100px");
```

In old browsers that don’t support `Array.from` or the iteration methods, you can still use [`Array.prototype.slice.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7056925).
Then you can iterate over it like you would with a real array:

```js
var elements = Array.prototype.slice
    .call(document.getElementsByClassName("myElement"));

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
  elements[i].style.size = "100px";
}
```

You can also iterate over the `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` itself, but be aware that in most circumstances, these collections are *live* ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#live_vs._static_nodelists), [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-collection-live)), i.e. they are updated as the DOM changes.
So if you insert or remove elements as you loop, make sure to not accidentally [skip over some elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15562484) or [create an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9709351).
MDN documentation should always note if a method returns a live collection or a static one.

For example, a `NodeList` offers some iteration methods such as `forEach` in modern browsers:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".myElement")
  .forEach((element) => element.style.size = "100px");
```

A simple `for` loop can also be used:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
  elements[i].style.size = "100px";
}
```

Aside: [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) yields a *live* `NodeList` and [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) yields a *live* `HTMLCollection`, so these two getters also need to be handled carefully.

---

There are some libraries like [jQuery](https://jquery.com) which make DOM querying a bit shorter and create a layer of abstraction over “one element” and “a collection of elements”:

```js
$(".myElement").css("size", "100px");
```

Comment: Does that also apply to `<iframe>` which is also part of your domain

Comment: It's 2018... Just create a wrapper function for `querySelectorAll()` and you can have nice short code without a large, old-school dependency. `qSA(".myElement").forEach(el => el.style.size = "100px")` Maybe have the wrapper receive a callback. `qSA(".myElement", el => el.style.size = "100px")`

Comment: "If you prefer something shorter, consider adding a huge library to your project"
I know 2012 was a different time, but even then I would've found that bit to be ludicrous.

Comment: "*Iterate over it like you would with a real array…* Careful, *getElementsByClassName* returns a **live** NodeList that might be unexpectedly modified during the loop, e.g. if the classname that they were selected by is removed. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I’ve now mentioned this in an edit.

Comment: The reference to jQuery should probably be removed from this answer, for various reasons: it behaves significantly differently from native DOM methods, it’s not directly relevant to the question asked, and it requires loading a library that is too big just to shorten one or two function calls. The last concern has been valid almost a decade ago, but is even more relevant today as jQuery is losing relevance. Granted, some browsers may cache jQuery internally, but do we really want new devs to adopt the practice of loading a huge library just to use a small subset from it?

Answer (score 26):

You are using a array as an object, the difference between `getElementbyId` and 
`getElementsByClassName` is that:

- `getElementbyId` will return an [Element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) or null if no element with the ID is found
- `getElementsByClassName` will return a [live HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), possibly of length 0 if no matching elements are found

### getElementsByClassName

> The `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` method takes a string that
>   contains an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens
>   representing classes. When called, the method must return a live
>   `NodeList` object containing all the elements in the document that
>   have all the classes specified in that argument, having obtained the
>   classes by splitting a string on spaces. If there are no tokens
>   specified in the argument, then the method must return an empty
>   NodeList.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname

### getElementById

> The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

in your code the lines:

> 1- document.getElementsByClassName('myElement').style.size = '100px';

will **NOT** work as expected, because the `getElementByClassName` will return an array, and the array will **NOT** have the `style` property, you can access each `element` by iterating through them.

That's why the function `getElementById` worked for you, this function will return the direct object. Therefore you will be able to access the `style` property.

Comment: Note that the [whatwg specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) that are being implemented by the browsers do differ from the w3c ones here, the former (and hence current browsers) return an HTMLCollection for getElementsByClassName, not a NodeList. Minor, but may confuse some.

Comment: @Kaiido—the practical difference being…? To my understanding, a [*NodeList*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) is a generic collection of DOM elements and is available in any DOM, not just an HTML DOM (e.g. an XML DOM), whereas an HTMLCollection is for HTML DOMs (obviously). The only difference I can see is the *namedItem* method of an [*HTMLCollection*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection).

Comment: PS Nit pick: link for the [*WHATWG HTML Living Standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org) and the [*W3C HTML 5.2 standard*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/). Spoilt by choice. ;-) Makes no difference to the point you raised though.

Comment: @RobG NodeList has [many methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Methods) that are not accessible on HTMLCollection.

Comment: @Kaiido—sure, but *forEach* isn't specified as part of the interface for either collection or NodeList by W3C or WHATWG, it's specified separately, e.g. as a property of generic collections in the [*Web IDL* specification](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-forEach) so *should* apply to both collections and NodeLists (though I accept your point that the collection returned by *getElementsByClassName* doesn't have a *forEach* method). I guess the bottom line is that there's enough of a story for a good answer to tell it. :-)

Comment: @RobG I don't get your point really... I said it's "minor", though I had to make the correction because of your edit, and then to point at the discrepancy my own edit made between the quote used by Alvaro Joao, and the edited sentence. Yes, NodeList do have ArrayLike methods because their <Node> attr is `iterable`

Answer (score 16):

**ES6** provides [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method, which creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

setTimeout(() => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(v => v.style.background = 'green');
  console.log(Array.from(boxes));
}, 500);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

As you can see inside the code snippet, after using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function you are then able to manipulate over each element.

The same solution using **`jQuery`**.

```js
$('.box').css({'background':'green'});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

The following description is taken from [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp):

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be
> accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.
>
> Tip: You can use the  length property of the NodeList object to determine the number of elements with a specified class name, then you can loop through all elements and extract the info you want.

So, as a parameter `getElementsByClassName` would accept a class name.

If this is your HTML body:

```
<div id="first" class="menuItem"></div>
<div id="second" class="menuItem"></div>
<div id="third" class="menuItem"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

then `var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menuItem')` would return a collection (not an array) of the 3 upper `<div>`s, as they match the given class name.

You can then iterate over this nodes (`<div>`s in this case) collection with:

```
for (var menuItemIndex = 0 ; menuItemIndex < menuItems.length ; menuItemIndex ++) {
   var currentMenuItem = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
   // do stuff with currentMenuItem as a node.
}
```

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object) for more on differences between elements and nodes.

Answer (score 8):

**In Other Words**

- `document.querySelector()` selects only the first **one** element of the specified selector. So it doesn't spit out an array, it's a single value. Similar to `document.getElementById()` which fetches ID-elements only, since IDs have to be unique.
- `document.querySelectorAll()` selects **all** elements with the specified selector and returns them in an array. Similar to `document.getElementsByClassName()` for classes and `document.getElementsByTagName()` tags only.

**Why use querySelector?**

It's used merely for the sole purpose of ease and brevity.

**Why use getElement/sBy?***

Faster performance.

**Why this performance difference?**

Both ways of selection has the purpose of creating a **NodeList** for further use. 
**querySelectors** generates a static NodeList with the selectors thus it must be first created from scratch.
**getElement/sBy*** immediately adapts the existing live NodeList of the current DOM.

So, when to use which method it's up to you/your project/your device.

**Infos**

[Demo of all methods](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/teu8nbd4/)
[NodeList Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
[Performance Test](https://jsperf.com/different-types-of-selecting)

Answer (score 7):

You could get a single element by running

```
document.querySelector('.myElement').style.size = '100px';
```

but it's going to work for the first element with class .myElement.

If you would like apply this for all elements with the class I suggest you to use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myElement').forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.size = '100px';
});
```

Comment: super old school solution:

   [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), function (el) {
     el.style.size = '100px';
  });

Answer (score 5):

It returns Array-like list.

**You make that an Array as example**

```
var el = getElementsByClassName("elem");
el = Array.prototype.slice.call(el); //this line
el[0].appendChild(otherElem);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/*
 * To hide all elements with the same class, 
 * use looping to reach each element with that class. 
 * In this case, looping is done recursively
 */

const hideAll = (className, i=0) => {
if(!document.getElementsByClassName(className)[i]){ //exits the loop when element of that id does not exist
  return; 
}

document.getElementsByClassName(className)[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'; //hide element
return hideAll(className, i+1) //loop for the next element
}

hideAll('appBanner') //the function call requires the class name
```

Answer (score 2):

With any browser supporting ES5+ (any browser basically above IE8) you can use the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('answer'), function(el) {
    el.style.color= 'red';
});
```

[caniuse source](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_foreach)

Answer (score 1):

So I was told that this is a duplicate from my question and I should delete mine, which I will do so I can keep the forum clean and keep the right to make questions.

As I think mine and this question are really different I will point out the answer to mine, so I will complete the knowledge in this page and the information will not be lost.

**Question**

1. I have a code in the snippet that has a `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]`, what the `[0]` is doing?
2. I never seen a square brackets being used in `getElementsByClassName` for what purpose is it used for?
3. Also, how can I convert it to jQuery?

**Answer**

1. The code in the snippet has a `[0]` it is actually being used as a array and as it is a 0 it is referring to the first time the appointed class is being used.
2. Same thing above.
3. I couldn't really do it and no one answered it. In the part of the code that is refering to `event. target` I can not use `$("#myModal")` instead of `document.getElementById("myModal")`, I think they should equivalent, but in this case the jQuery form substituting the standard one will not result in the desired effect.

```
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal </h2>

<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**update**

It seems I can't really delete mine question and people are unsatisfied with it, I really don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Super old school solution:

```
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), function (el) {
            el.style.size = '100px';
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

An answer **for Drenzii's specific case**...

You could make **a function that will work for any of the `word` elements** and pass in the number of the one you want to transform, like:

```js
// Binds `wordButtons` to an (array-like) HTMLCollection of buttons
const wordButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("word");

// Applies the `slantWord` function to the first word button
slantWord(1);

// Defines the `slantWord` function
function slantWord(wordNumber) {
  const index = wordNumber - 1; // Collection index is zero-based
  wordButtons[index].style.transform = "rotate(7deg)"; // Transforms the specified button
}
```

```html
<div class="wordGameContainer">
  <button class="word word1">WORD 1</button>
  <button class="word word2">WORD 2</button>
  <button class="word word3">WORD 3</button>
  <button class="word word4">WORD 4</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="moveWord()" class="playButton">PLAY</button>
</div>
```